# AWS Credentials in a Docker Desktop deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, credentials, .net-6.0

I am working on a .net 6.0 application that will run in an EKS cluster, but I am developing using Docker Desktop and Kubernetes. Whilst I can pass in the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, etc via the Helm Chart as Environment variables the issue I am facing is that I keep seeing **The security token included in the request is expired**, I can update the values and redeploy but clearly that is a pain to do.

When this is running in EKS it will use IAM Roles etc so isn't an issue but just wondered if anyone has a solution for doing this locally. If I run up the code in VS rather than Docker it picks up the credentials from the aws credentials file and runs (even though I haven't updated the token).

[image]

In the code snippet above the environment var is set to **local** when running in my Docker Desktop Kubernetes.

Any ideas if there is a solution for this?

Comment: So your access key ID & secret access key are clearly temporary. Do you use `docker-compose`?

Comment: If so, you basically have to read-only mount your AWS credentials file onto the Docker image(s) using volumes and that way, your Docker container will have access to your AWS credentials file :)

Comment: That would be the safest & easiest way

Comment: `volumes: - ~/.aws/:/root/.aws:ro` is what you need

Comment: Change `~` to `%UserProfile%` if on Windows or even better would probably be `$HOME`. If you have multiple profiles, also set the `AWS_PROFILE` env var. Does that work for you?

Comment: Thanks for these ideas I'll try them out

Comment: Any results? :)

Comment: It was a bit more complex than that as I am using a helm chart. I have that creating the volume but copying the file is more tricky. I have been able to create the file programmatically but it still complains about the token being expired. I will update on progress.

Comment: You don’t need to copy anything, just mount it!

Comment: Do you have an example of how to do that in a Helm chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this eventually, I was working on other aspects of the project so have only just come back to the problem.

As I am deploying with a helm chart I needed to setup the volume in the deployment mapping the volume requires the path of the folder to be prefixed with:

/run/desktop/mnt/host/

so the yaml will looks something like this:

```
volumes:
   - name: dev-aws-creds
     hostPath:
        path: /run/desktop/mnt/host/c/Users/simon/.aws/
        type: Directory

volumeMounts:
   - name: dev-aws-creds
     mountPath: /.aws/
```

Note the volume is not read only it seems that the AWS code writes back a value to the file. As suggested I needed to provide the desired profile in the AWS_PROFILE environment and also you can specify the credentials folder with the env var AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE.

Also if your profile has any sso values it doesn't seem to work so it makes sense to have a profile that specifically is for your containers like the following.

```
[docker]
aws_access_key_id=<access_key_id>
aws_secret_access_key=<secret_access_key>
aws_session_token=<session_token>
```

I still need to refresh these when the values expire but it means that I only need to do it in one place rather than modify environment variables in each helm chart.

Answer (score 0):

Why can’t your create a test user in aws & use its keys & secret for your local test. As it’s user & not role that you need to assume keys & secrets for test user will never be expired.

Comment: Unfortunately that's against the company policy